# Why is this cstring initialization not wrong?

Tags: c++, c-strings

I know Example 1 below is syntactically right but can the same be said about example 2?
Why is Example 2 not throwing a compiler error?
I have never seen this form of C-string initialization in any C++ book I have read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //Example 1;
    const char STR_1[] = "your_cstring";
    std::cout << STR_1 << "\n\n";

    //Example 2
    const char STR_2[] =  "your_cstring  "
                          "your_cstring1 "
                          "your_cstring2 ";
    std::cout << STR_2 << "\n\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
your_cstring

your_cstring  your_cstring1 your_cstring2
```

Thanks a lot and much appreciated.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479995/quotation-mark-in-return-c or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327148/compilation-of-string-literals

Answer (score 3):

[Adjacent string literals are concatenated.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)

This:

```
const char STR_2[] =  "your_cstring  "
                      "your_cstring1 "
                      "your_cstring2 ";
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
const char STR_2[] =  "your_cstring  your_cstring1 your_cstring2 ";
```

That being said, use `std::string` (C++) instead of `char[]` (C) unless you have a very good reason.